# Adjust position of second nodeset based on given coords of first nodeset in two-mode igraph plot

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

I would like to adjust the position of a second nodeset based on the given coordinates of a first nodeset for a two-mode plot with igraph. Is there a convenient way of doing so?

Here is a replicable example that shows what I would like to do.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(01)

# get sample matrix
bip <- matrix(sample(0:1,10*20, replace=TRUE),10,20)

# transform to bipartite incidence matrix for plotting
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(bip)

# initialise empty matrix for coords of the first nodeset
layout_given <- matrix(0, 10, 2)
# sample some coordinates that represent those which are given 
layout_given[,1] <- sample(-2.435651:3.670977,10, replace = T)
layout_given[,2] <- sample(-2.435651:3.670977,10, replace = T)

# these are the standard positions of the nodes the algorithm 
# layout.fruchterman.reingold assigns
layout_fr = layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)

# replace the given positions with those generated by the algorithm. 
# these are the first 10 in the layout 30x2 layout matrix 
# (because there are 10 nodes of the first nodeset) with those that I would like 
# to hold fixed
layout_fr[1:10,] <- layout_given


plot(g, 
 layout = layout_fr,
 vertex.shape= c("circle", "square")[V(g)$type+1],
 vertex.color= c("red", "orange")[V(g)$type+1])
```

The plot shows that positioning of the second nodeset is not optimised for readability with regards to the first nodeset. This interferes with the readability of the graph. 
How can I optimise the position of the second nodeset based on the given positioning in the first nodeset `layout_given`?

[image]

There must be a way to do that but my coding knowledge is too limited to understand the way `layout.fruchterman.reingold()` is coded to understand how to apply it conditional on the given coordinates for the first nodeset.

Comment: Why not use a [bipartite layout](https://igraph.org/r/doc/layout_as_bipartite.html)?

Comment: Good idea but if it was possible to solve this puzzle it would absolutely great, especially for plotting two-mode networks with one geo-referenced node set

Comment: The link in my first comment leads you to the documentation for computing a bipartite layout in igraph for R. I suggest you start there.

Comment: I don't think `layout_as_bipartite()` actually helps because the real network that I have consists of about 30 nodes of the first node type and more than 200 of the second nodeset, so it is difficult to see which nodes of the first node type are connected with the second node type. Any further suggestions? In addition, I have second network one-mode network that I plot underneath, so I guess it would be better to use `fruchtermann.reingold` ?

Comment: I've also tried to use a projection but that does not help that much either.

Comment: I think you should post a photo of a hand-drawn picture displaying your ideal layout, and provide a link to your data and code to construct the graph. Otherwise, we can just guess what might help.

Comment: However, pretty much no matter which layout, any random or approximately random graph with >50-100 nodes will always look like a hairball. The bipartite layout algorithm tries to minimize edge crossings, which maximizes your chance to be able to see differences in the connectivity between different nodes. But there is only so much you can do in untangling 30 * 200+ relationships in 2 dimensions.

Comment: Well I would just like to apply the fruchtermann.reingold algorithm conditional on the given node positions of the first node set. The graph is readable with this algorithm but as I have a geo-referenced first node set, it would make more sense to use these positions for it and then optimise the second node set based on the first node set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193358/discussion-between-s-front-and-paul-brodersen).